# Avconv creates 0 byte outputfile after applying frame rate reduction

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, video-encoding, avconv

I installed avconv because I am too stupid to install ffmpeg, 
now I realized I am even more stupid. 
I tried to reduce the framrate from 30 fps to 24 fps following a very straigtforward tutorial:

```
 # avconv -i jeff_western2.mp4 -r 24 jeff_24.mp4
avconv version 9.18-6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 16 2015 13:19:10 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'jeff_western2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf54.63.104
  Duration: 00:01:03.76, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 4652 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile), yuv420p, 720x480 [PAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], 4528 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 30k tbc
    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 127 kb/s
[libx264 @ 0xa0bec0] using SAR=8/9
[libx264 @ 0xa0bec0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.1 Cache64
[libx264 @ 0xa0bec0] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0xa0bec0] 264 - core 142 r2389 956c8d8 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=24 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.25 aq=1:1.00
encoder 'aac' is experimental and might produce bad results.
Add '-strict experimental' if you want to use it.
```

Since there was not much to do wrong in following the tutorial I do not know where to search for the problem.

Comment: I guess 0 bytes of output is the most perfect possible reduction in frame rate. Can't do much more reduction than that! :-) More seriously, did you try with `-strict experimental` as the message suggests? By the way: I think that `ffmpeg` and `avconv` are actually the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The last line states:

Add `-strict experimental` if you want to use it.

so maybe try this:

```
avconv -i jeff_western2.mp4 -r 24 -strict experimental jeff_24.mp4
```